# How to integrate LibreOffice Help files with a portable version of LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice

I've downloaded LibreOffice Help .MSI package and installed it into a separate folder. Now, how to make Help run on *F1*? I need to learn how to create Writer documents in landscape mode. Strangely, in *Tools>Options...>Paths* there's no option to define the location of the Help folder. Thanks in advance.

(I **sincerely hope** that developers of LibreOffice will see this question.)

Answer (score 0):

#### How to make Help run on `F1`?

The help files are a separate download:

> [image]

Source: [Download LibreOffice | LibreOffice - Free Office Suite - Based on OpenOffice - Compatible with Microsoft](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/)

Comment: But the question was about the *portable* version: How to apply that installation package to a portable version?